# React Native Expo Toggle Audio On and Off

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to toggle a sound on and off across my react native expo app, however it's resulting sound overlapping when I click multiple times on and off & I am unsure if I need to set state on audio? I couldn't seem to find any good examples here - https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/av/ unsure what I am doing wrong, newbie to RN.

As you can see this is a headerbutton which has to work across the whole app not just one screen.

Here is my snack - https://snack.expo.io/@roshambo/sound-toggle-on-and-off

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { HeaderButton } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

const CustomHeaderButton = props => {
const [soundIcon, setSoundIcon] = useState(false);

const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
(async () => {
  await soundObject.loadAsync(require("../assets/bglaughs.mp3"), {
    volume: 0.25,
    isLooping: true,
    shouldPlay: true,
    isMuted: true
  });
})();

const toggleSound = () => {
  setSoundIcon(prevState => !prevState);
  soundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(this._onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
};

_onPlaybackStatusUpdate = playbackStatus => {
  if (playbackStatus.isMuted) {
    playSound();
  } else {
    stopSound();
  }
};

const stopSound = async () => {
  try {
    await soundObject.stopAsync();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("sound couldn't pause");
  }
};

const playSound = async () => {
  try {
    await soundObject.setIsMutedAsync(false);
    await soundObject.playAsync();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("sound couldn't play");
  }  
};

return (
<HeaderButton
  {...props}
  IconComponent={Ionicons}
  iconSize={23}
  iconName={soundIcon ? "ios-volume-high" : "ios-volume-off"}
  onPress={toggleSound}
  />
  );
};

export default CustomHeaderButton;
```

**UPDATE:**

**Here is my working code based off Oleg's answer as well as my implementation on redux.**

**Component**

```
import React from "react";
import { HeaderButton } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import * as soundActions from "../store/actions/sound-action";

import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const CustomHeaderButton = props => {

  const sound = useSelector(state => state.sound.soundState);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <HeaderButton
      {...props}
      IconComponent={Ionicons}
      iconSize={23}
      iconName={sound === "playing" ? "ios-volume-high" : "ios-volume-off"}
      onPress={() => {
        dispatch(soundActions.toggleSound(sound));
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomHeaderButton;
```

**Reducer**

```
import { TOGGLE_SOUND } from "../actions/sound-action";

import { Audio } from "expo-av";

const initialState = {
  soundState: "nosound"
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_SOUND:
      if (state.soundState === "nosound") {
        (async () => {
          const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
            require("../../assets/bglaughs.mp3"),
            {
              shouldPlay: true,
              volume: 0.25,
              isLooping: true
            }
          );
          this.sound = sound;
        })();
        return {
          ...state,
          soundState: "playing"
        };
      } else if (state.soundState === "playing") {
        (async () => {
          if (this.sound !== null) {
            await this.sound.pauseAsync();
          }
        })();
        return { ...state, soundState: "donepause" };
      } else if (state.soundState === "donepause") {
        (async () => {
          await this.sound.playAsync();
        })();
        return { soundState: "playing" };
      }
  }
  return state;
};
```

Comment: Can you provide expo snack related to question?

Comment: Here is my snack - https://snack.expo.io/@roshambo/sound-toggle-on-and-off

Comment: Hi I am wondering now with my component although it seems to work for my app, do I need redux-thunk to handle async await request ?

Comment: yes,if you want to implement in redux like i described early.

Comment: I thought that redux reducers were only meant to contain "clean js" that didn't call external files/api/load libraries etc...

Comment: Ah yes, I should extract that and put it in the action and pass it as a payload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created snack answer for your question: 
You have to pay attention to new way create sound and flag loop set to false.

https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/sound-toggle-on-and-off

Comment: Thank you Oleg your answer works, I refactored it to use react hook useState instead, I will repost my answer soon!

Comment: As my code suggests I am using thie on and off sound in the header of the app so I am wondering also is it best to use redux to manage global state of this on and off sound? as it seems to work ok properly in one stack ?

Comment: You can work also with redux and look at sound api like to fetch api pattern if you want. Another way is working with local States of Components without all this stuff.

Comment: So would redux be best choice to manage the state of the sound across the whole app? As what I understand the I have implemented the localState which only works on one screen

Comment: If you already started working with redux in your app and want to separate sound api functionality for sharing to app level, you can create sound api service and use it like fetch api way/style...

Answer (score 2):

After reading expo documentation, I came up with this solution.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

export default AudioFile = (props) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState('play-arrow');

  const playAudioHandler = async (url) => {
    if (isLoaded == true) {
      if (isPlaying == true) {
        await soundObject.pauseAsync();
        setIsPlaying(false);
        setIcon('play-arrow');
      } else {
        await soundObject.playAsync();
        setIsPlaying(true);
        setIcon('pause');
      }
    } else {
      try {
        await soundObject.loadAsync({ uri: url });
        await soundObject
          .playAsync()
          .then(async (playbackStatus) => {
            console.log(playbackStatus);
            setIcon('pause');
            setIsPlaying(playbackStatus.isPlaying);
            setIsLoaded(playbackStatus.isLoaded);
            setTimeout(() => {
              soundObject.unloadAsync();
              setIsLoaded(false);
              setIcon('play-arrow');
            }, playbackStatus.durationMillis);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: I think you made an error, it should be playbackStatus.durationMillis not palybackStatus.playableDurationMillis